# Primefaces datatable columnGroup header stomps on header facet with sortBy and filterBy

Tags: primefaces

My goal is to produce a table with two header rows. The first with a few column-spanning cells, the second with all 1-cell headers, but with sortBy and filterBy enabled.

```
<p:dataTable ....  >
  <p:columnGroup type="header">
    <p:row>
      <p:column colspan="3" headerText="my header 1" />
      <p:column colspan="3" headerText="my header 2" />
    </p:row>
  </p:columnGroup>
  <p:column sortBy="#{myBean.var1}" filterBy="#{myBean.var1}" headerText="var1">
    <h:outputText value="#{...var1}" />
  </p:column>
  .
  .
</p:dataTable>
```

I can get either the columnGroup to show up or the per-column headerText with sortBy and filterBy, but not both. When I mix them, the header components from the per-column header row disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is possible to nest dataTables via the subTable component. This showcase example demonstrates [nesting a subTable in a larger dataTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableSubTable.jsf), there-by achieving filtering and sorting combined with columnGroups in the headers.

Comment: A word of warning, this complicates row selection.